# merge 2 sql statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two two sql statements:
SQL 1:

```
SELECT
[PO].[No.],
[PO].[SD],
[PO].[oNo.],
[PO].[StCN],
[POL].[OC] as S_text
FROM [PO]
  INNER JOIN 
  [POL]
  ON [POL].[No.] = [PO].[No.]
    INNER JOIN ( 
      SELECT [POL].[No.], 
      MAX([POL].[Line No.])as MaxLine
      FROM [POL]
      WHERE [POL].[EP]='1'
      GROUP BY [POL].[No.] 
      ) as MaxLineTable
      ON [POL].[No.] = MaxLineTable.[No.]
    AND [POL].[Line No.] = MaxLineTable.MaxLine
  WHERE [PO].[Status] <> 3
  AND [PO].[Plant] = '0025'
  ORDER BY [PO].[SD]
```

Result of the SQL statement:

```
NO.  |  SD    |  oNo  |  StCN  |  S_text
P001 | 1/1/16 | O100  |  CustA | Step 2
P002 | 2/1/16 | O100  |  CustA | Step 59
P006 | 9/1/16 | O103  |  CustC | Step 10
P005 | 1/2/16 | O101  |  CustB | Step 4
```

and SQL 2:

```
SELECT
[PO].[No.],
[PO].[SD],
[PO].[oNo.],
[PO].[StCN],
"Some Tekst" as S_text
FROM [PO]
WHERE [PO].[Status] <> 3
AND [PO].[Plant] = '0025' 
ORDER BY [PO].[SD]
```

Result of the SQL statement:

```
NO.  |  SD    |  oNo  |  StCN  |  S_text
P001 | 1/1/16 | O100  |  CustA | Some Text
P003 | 1/1/16 | O104  |  CustC | Some Text
P002 | 2/1/16 | O100  |  CustA | Some Text
P006 | 9/1/16 | O103  |  CustC | Some Text
P005 | 1/2/16 | O101  |  CustB | Some Text
P004 | 6/2/16 | O207  |  CustA | Some Text
```

SQL 1 is always a subset of sql2. What i would like is the result of sql 2, with the additional information of S_text in all rows.

The output I would like to have:

```
NO.  |  SD    |  oNo  |  StCN  |  S_text
P001 | 1/1/16 | O100  |  CustA | Step 2
P003 | 1/1/16 | O104  |  CustC | Some Text
P002 | 2/1/16 | O100  |  CustA | Step 59
P006 | 9/1/16 | O103  |  CustC | Step 10
P005 | 1/2/16 | O101  |  CustB | Step 4
P004 | 6/2/16 | O207  |  CustA | Some Text
```

Comment: Is not clear ..please update your question, provide a proper sample and the expected result

Comment: I've added the results of both the first and second SQL and also an example of the expected result.

Comment: If your first result set is *always* a subset of the second result, then you should already have the information you need.  Also, why is this tagged `plsql` if we're dealing with SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a  left join between the two select

```
select No, SD, oNo, StCN, ISNULL(t2.S_text, "Some Tekst" )
FROM  (
  SELECT
    [PO].[No.] as No,
    [PO].[SD] as SD ,
    [PO].[oNo.] as oNo,
    [PO].[StCN] as StCN   
    FROM [PO]
    WHERE [PO].[Status] <> 3
    AND [PO].[Plant] = '0025' 
) t1 
left  join (
  SELECT
    [PO].[No.] as No,
    [PO].[SD] as SD ,
    [PO].[oNo.] as oNo,
    [PO].[StCN] as StCN   
    [POL].[OC] as S_text
    FROM [PO]
    INNER JOIN 
    [POL]
      ON [POL].[No.] = [PO].[No.]
    INNER JOIN ( 
      SELECT [POL].[No.], 
      MAX([POL].[Line No.])as MaxLine
      FROM [POL]
      WHERE [POL].[EP]='1'
      GROUP BY [POL].[No.] 
    ) as MaxLineTable
       ON [POL].[No.] = MaxLineTable.[No.]
          AND [POL].[Line No.] = MaxLineTable.MaxLine
    WHERE [PO].[Status] <> 3
    AND [PO].[Plant] = '0025'
) t2
left  join 
ORDER BY t1.[SD]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried your solution but get the message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'"
When I remove the last line, I get the error message "Line 36: Incorrect syntax near 'join' "

Comment: Try removing the "left join" (second to last line of TSQL) just before the last line starting with "ORDER BY".  It is producing both errors.